# Heroku slug size calculation?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, build, heroku

How does Heroku calculate slug size?

I was doing a simple Google web toolkit web app. I used Spring Roo to help me with the boiler code and it created a small app *"expenses"*, the same app as showed at Google IO.

To the generated POM.xml file  I added a *<artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>* as one do in the spring mvc tutorial for Heroku.

Now when I run `git push heroku master` in the terminal maven start fetching dependencies on the Heroku side and I get `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS` but then Heroku rejects my push.

```
-----> Push rejected, your compiled slug is 138.0MB (max is 100MB).
   See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size !     Heroku push rejected, slug too large
```

My generated war file ends up 31Mb when locally created. But the target directory ends up something like the compiled slug size so I added a slugignore file.

```
$ cat .slugignore
target/*
!target/*.war
```

Pushed up this to Heroku and it still throws this at me `Push rejected, your compiled slug is 138.0MB (max is 100MB).`

So my question is Heroku calculate its slug size? I have read their documentation but it's very sparse.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml and .gitignore files?

Comment: Yes here they are. Hopefully they are intact as I have worked some more but I have fetched them from another branch. http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/6LY2AQrCOkJdXx9wVHqJQQ

Comment: I don't see anything in there that seems like it would cause the slug size to be so large.  Can you file a support request?  http://support.heroku.com/

Comment: Done, I filed a low prio request as it's only for play and not production :)

Comment: would be cool if you could write if this was resolved somehow!

Comment: No it wasn't resolved and I haven't pursed it. Started to play with Scala and play instead :)

Comment: I suspect your issue is that slug size will include `.m2/repository` - not the entirety of your local one, but what would be generated if you wiped your own repo and recreated just for this app with all dependencies. I will attempt to replicate this later.

Comment: May be it's worth to make all your maven dependencies optional? And to play with exclusions then. You can use maven org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin to generate list of all dependencies of your project and then see how much do they weight.

Comment: Try to use [jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/). Slug size will be minimum, since the entire application will be built on-fly

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the first links on Google for this, I figured I'd add the solution that I found, via a simple blog post by Chris Auer which details adding a maven plugin execution: http://enlightenmint.com/blog/2012/06/22/reducing-slug-size-for-heroku.html

EDIT: based on oers comment, the highlights from the above link are to declare the maven-clean-plugin in your plugin executions and include the target/ directory (and all subdirectories) while excluding *.war files.  The executions phase of that plugin should be invoked on the install phase (not just the clean phase).

In it's entirety (in case that site goes down), it looks about like this:

```
<plugins>
....
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>target/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>dependency/*.jar</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.war</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
....
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Slug size from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Your slug size is displayed at the end of a successful compile. You can roughly estimate slug size locally by doing a fresh checkout of your app, deleting the .git directory, and running du -hsc.

```
$ du -hsc | grep total
```

Comment: Given that the original question was about a Java app, the calculation above should also be done after app compilation (via `mvn package`) to include the build output.

Comment: @ryanbrainard Yes. It sounds reasonable. Also it gives you some thought about transitive dependencies management.

Comment: Java apps on Heroku already need to copy in all transitive dependencies, so these would be included in the calculation. For example see the use of `copy-dependencies` bound to `package` in this sample project https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-java/blob/master/pom.xml